# CSS Dropdown menu not working in IE (All versions)

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am having some issues with a CSS drop down menu that floats in another navigation div. It works perfectly ok in all browsers except IE.
This is the script that sits on the pages (And yes it it is the correct Doctype).

```
<div id="topbar">
<h2 style="color: #2d2d2d; padding: 20px;">
 <a class="topbar" href="/index.php">Site Title</a><span style="float:right; clear:right; 
margin-top: -32px; ">
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
<li class='active has-sub'><a href='/profile.php'><span>
  Profile Name        </span></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/profile.php">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="/editaccount.php">Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
     </span> </div>



> #cssmenu{    height:37px;    display:block;    padding:0;    margin:20px auto;     border:1px solid;    border-radius:5px;    }
> 
>    #cssmenu > ul {list-style:inside none; padding:0; margin:0;}   
> #cssmenu > ul > li {list-style:inside none; padding:0; margin:0; float:left;    display:block; position:relative;}
> 
>    /* Styling navigation links */    #cssmenu > ul > li > a{   
> outline:none;    display:block;    position:relative;    padding:12px
> 20px;    font:bold 13px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;   
> text-align:center;    text-decoration:none;    text-shadow:1px 1px 0
> rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);    }
> 
>    #cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a{border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;}
> 
> 
>    /* Extra border for navigation links */    #cssmenu > ul > li >
> a:after{    content:'';    position:absolute;    border-right:1px
> solid;    top:-1px; bottom:-1px; right:-2px;    z-index:99;    }   
> #cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > a:after{top:0; bottom:0;}
> 
>    /* Bullet for dropdowns */    #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub >
> a:before{    content:'';    position:absolute; top:18px; right:6px;   
> border:5px solid transparent;    border-top:5px solid #fff;    }   
> #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before{top:19px;}
> 
>    /* Hover state styles for drop menu link */    #cssmenu ul
> li.has-sub:hover > a{    background:#3f3f3f;    border-color:#ccc;   
> padding-bottom:13px; padding-top:13px;    top:-1px;    z-index:999;   
> }
> 
>    /* Show dropdown when hover */    #cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover >
> ul, #cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > div{display:block;}    #cssmenu ul
> li.has-sub > a:hover{background:#3f3f3f; border-color:#ccc;}
> 
>    /* Dropdown styles */    #cssmenu ul li > ul, #cssmenu ul li > div{
> display:none; width:auto;    position:absolute; top:38px;   
> padding:10px 0;    background:#3f3f3f;    border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;  
> z-index:999;    }
> 
>    /* Dropdown list style */    #cssmenu ul li > ul{width:200px;}   
> #cssmenu ul li > ul li{display:block; list-style:inside none; padding:0; margin:0;    position:relative;}    #cssmenu ul li > ul li
> a{    outline:none; display:block;    position:relative;    margin:0;
> padding:8px 20px;    color:#fff;    text-decoration:none;   
> text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);    }
> 
>    /* Dropdown box styles */    #cssmenu ul li > div{width:auto;
> padding:20px;}    #cssmenu ul li > div p{    font:9pt/150%;
> color:#fff;    text-align:justify;    text-shadow:1px 1px 0
> rgba(0,0,0,0.5);    margin:0;    }
> 
>    #cssmenu ul li > div h1{    position:relative;    margin:0 0 12px
> 0;    padding-bottom:10px;    border-bottom:1px solid #222;   
> font:bold 13pt; color:#bbb;    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
> }    #cssmenu ul li > div h1:after{    content:'';    height:0;
> padding:0;    position:absolute; bottom:-2px; left:0; right:0;   
> border-bottom:1px solid #555;    }
```

Comment: goto : Jsbin.com , paste the css + html in the appropriate section , paste the  URL here.

Comment: Hi @RoyiNamir That does not solve the issue because it displays correctly in there and not in IE either....

Comment: great  , this link that you'll provide , we'll open it in IE. ( the link is just like an email. anyone can open it in any browser)

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle link **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/7YDUS/17/)**

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    }
body {
    font:normal 12px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
    }
ul, li, ol {
    list-style-type:none;
    }

.wrapper {
    width:95%;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px  solid green;
}
.spacer {
    clear:both;
    font-size:0;
    line-height:0;
    height:0;
    }

h2 {
    float:left;
    color:#2d2d2d;
    padding:20px;
    }
#cssmenu{
    height:37px;
    display:block;
    padding:0;
    border:1px solid;
    border-radius:5px;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
    list-style:inside none; 
    padding:0; 
    margin:0;
    }   
#cssmenu > ul > li {
    list-style:inside none; 
    padding:0; 
    margin:0; 
    float:left;    
    display:block; 
    position:relative;
    }

/* Styling navigation links */    
#cssmenu > ul > li > a{   
    outline:none;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    padding:12px 20px;
    font:bold 13px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;   
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);    
    }
   #cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a{border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;}


/* Extra border for navigation links */    
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:after{
    content:''; 
    position:absolute;    
    border-right:1px solid;    
    top:-1px; bottom:-1px; right:-2px;   
    z-index:99;    
     }   
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > a:after{
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    }

/* Bullet for dropdowns */    
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before{    
    content:'';    
    position:absolute; 
    top:18px; 
    right:6px;   
    border:5px solid transparent;    
    border-top:5px solid #fff;    
    }   
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before{
    top:19px;
    }

/* Hover state styles for drop menu link */   
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > a{    
    background:#3f3f3f;   
    border-color:#ccc;   
    padding-bottom:13px; 
    padding-top:13px;    
    top:-1px;   
    z-index:999;   
    }

/* Show dropdown when hover */    
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > ul, #cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > div{
    display:block;
    }    
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:hover{
    background:#3f3f3f; 
    border-color:#ccc;
    }

/* Dropdown styles */   
#cssmenu ul li > ul, #cssmenu ul li > div{
    display:none; 
    width:auto;   
    position:absolute; 
    top:38px;  
    right: -2px;
    text-align: right; 
    padding:10px 0;    
    background:#3f3f3f;    
    border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;  
    z-index:999;   
     }

/* Dropdown list style */   
#cssmenu ul li > ul{width:200px;}   
#cssmenu ul li > ul li{
    display:block; 
    list-style:inside none; 
    padding:0; 
    margin:0;    
    position:relative;
    }    
#cssmenu ul li > ul li a{    
    outline:none; 
    display:block;    
    position:relative;   
    margin:0;
    padding:8px 20px;    
    color:#fff;   
    text-decoration:none;   
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);   
    }

/* Dropdown box styles */    
#cssmenu ul li > div{
width:auto;
padding:20px;
}    
#cssmenu ul li > div p{    
    font:9pt/150%;
    color:#fff;    
    text-align:justify;    
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0
    rgba(0,0,0,0.5);    
    margin:0;    
    }
#cssmenu ul li > div h1{    
    position:relative;    
    margin:0 0 12px 0;    
    padding-bottom:10px;    
    border-bottom:1px solid #222;   
    font:bold 13pt; color:#bbb;    
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    }   
#cssmenu ul li > div h1:after{   
    content:'';   
    height:0;
    padding:0;   
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-2px; 
    left:0; 
    right:0;   
    border-bottom:1px solid #555;  
    }
```